# Is it possible to create a modified .apk (which can be installable on mpbile) from mobile and store it in external sd_card?

Tags: android, apk

I have an apk file in assets folder i want to modify it (insert a file in to it) from mobile and store it in external sd_card(that can be installabe in mobile). How it is possible?

Comment: You may have to reverse engineer it by APKTool and then repackage it, long and hard job to do

Comment: @MohsenAfshin I don't know how to use APKTool.How it is possible by using APKTool send me some related links for that.

Answer (score 0):

you cant change apk file. and by any means if you able to change then it will work or not its not sure